# CUDA out of memory on automatic1111 Stable Diffusion

Tags: python, pytorch, stable-diffusion

I'm running into an issue while running Stable Diffusion web UI AUTOMATIC1111. I have an RTX 2060 6GB, and I'm running into this issue.

```
OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. 
Tried to allocate 1.50 GiB 
 (GPU 0; 5.77 GiB total capacity; 3.34 GiB already allocated; 1.07 GiB free; 3.41 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) 
If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. 
See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Time taken: 57.59s

Torch active/reserved: 4200/4380 MiB, Sys VRAM: 5687/5910 MiB (96.23%)
```

I know it's a low amount of vram, but I didn't get this while running under Windows. I tried setting `max_split_size_mb` to 512mb

Comment: It's telling you what the problem is. You're trying to load a model that's too large for your GPU

Comment: yeah i get that, how come it's fine on windows then?

Comment: i just want to know if there's any optimizations that are no implemented yet on linux, so my switch of operating systems isn't as hellish as it is.